# Laravel Query Builder: CONCAT and JOIN

Tags: laravel, join, concatenation

I have a db as the following photo below, with three tables:

[tables][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G947f.jpg

I need to implement a query as table below:

```html
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>codProduto</th><th>codReserva</th><th>codClientes</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>20,30,40</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
$test = DB::table('clientes as c')
                       ->leftjoin('reservas as r', 'p.codReserva', '=', 'c.codCliente')
                       ->leftjoin('produtos as p', 'p.codProduto', '=', 'r.codReserva')
                       ->select('p.codProduto','r.codReserva',DB::raw("CONCAT(c.codCliente,', ') as codCliente"))
        ->get();
  dd($test);
```

can someone help me to implement that? thank you so much. I got something like this below

```
array:3[ 
0 => {#498 
  +"codProduto": 1
  +"codreserva": 2
  +"codCiente": 20,
}]
1 => {#498 
  +"codProduto": 1
  +"codreserva": 2
  +"codCiente": 30,
}] 
2 => {#498 
  +"codProduto": 1
  +"codreserva": 2
  +"codCiente": 40,
}]
```

but i'd like to get:

```
array:1[ 
0 => {#498 
  +"codProduto": 1
  +"codreserva": 2
  +"codCiente": 20,30,40
}]
```

Comment: can you show your db query which you wont to convert using Db??

Comment: array expected by query added ...

Answer (score 0):

just change query using group_concat like this:

```
$test = DB::table('clientes as c')
               ->leftjoin('reservas as r', 'r.codReserva', '=', 'b.ce_denunciacrime')
               ->leftjoin('produtos as p', 'p.codProduto', '=', 'r.codReserva')
               ->select('p.codProduto','r.codReserva',DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(c.codCliente,'') as codCliente"))
               ->limit(1)
               ->groupBy('p.codProduto','r.codReserva')
               ->get();
```